# How to setup a simple DNS server to answer just for one name and forward all the rest?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I would like to setup a small Linux (Ubuntu) server for a school project. This school server should forward all the request to the primary DNS server of the network and reply with an IPv6 address when asked for Google.com

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have used `dnsmasq` for similar things in the past.

First edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add the relevant entries so they resolve to the expected addresses when trying them locally (for example with `ping`). Then `apt-get install dnsmasq` and make sure `no-hosts` is commented *out* in the configuration file (it should be by default).

The way this works (by default) is: when having to resolve a name, `dnsmasq` first looks it up in your `hosts` file. If not found, it forwards it through the DNS servers configured on `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was searching for. Dnsmasq offers a plain and easy configuration file, I added a line to resolve google.com to an IPv6 address and it works like a charm without even touching resolv.conf!